# Powershell assign multiple ip addresses to adapter

Tags: networking, powershell, wmi, ip, adapter

I want to write a powershell script to create a loopback adapter and assign multiple ip addresses to it.  You can see where I am getting the adapter and then have an if statement that works based on whether or not it already exists. In the if statement I'll want to create and name the adapter.  Following that I want to assign multiple IP addresses to it.

I manually created the adapter.  My code is trying to assign ip addresses.  However, the ip addresses don't seem to be getting assigned.   Also, if you know how to create the loopback adapter in the first place let me know.

```
cls
# Get-wmiobject win32_NetworkAdapter 
$networkAdapter = Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapter | where{$_.ServiceName -eq 'msloop'}

if(!$networkAdapter)
{
    #"null"

}

"The following IP Addresses are already assigned:"
#Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "IPEnabled = $true" | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddress }

$adapterIndex = $networkAdapter.Index;
$adapterConfig = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Index = $adapterIndex AND ipenabled = 'true'");
$adapterConfig.IPAddress

$ip = @("192.168.200.1", "192.168.200.2", "192.168.200.3", "192.168.200.4", "192.168.200.5",  "192.168.200.6")
$dns = "255.255.255.0"
$adapterConfig.EnableStatic($ip, $dns)
$adapterConfig.IPAddress
```

Comment: Have you read this? http://blog.devstone.com/aaron/CategoryView,category,PowerShell.aspx

Comment: The following works.  How I'm half way there.  Just need to figure out how to create the adapter now...

    $ip = @("192.168.200.1", "192.168.200.2", "192.168.200.3", "192.168.200.4", "192.168.200.5", "192.168.200.6")
    #ridiculous! - the dns array size must match the ip array size or this will not work!
    $dns = @("255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0")
    $adapterConfig.EnableStatic($ip, $dns)

Comment: Anyone know how to create the adapter?

Comment: What you are calling $dns is actually the subnet mask, so that makes sense that you need to pair it with an address.